# Mount on filesystem of type eCryptfs explicitly disallowed due to known incompatibilities

Tags: mount, encryption, ecryptfs

I get this error when I'm trying to do `sudo mount -t ecryptfs folder1 folder2` in my home folder (encrypted by ubuntu)
I tried the same command but folders at /tmp, it worked as expected.

The error message I got:

```
  ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=16
  ecryptfs_cipher=aes
  ecryptfs_sig=66cea2017ad38853
Error mounting eCryptfs: [-22] Invalid argument
```

In `/var/log/syslog`:

```
kernel: [  197.621331] Mount on filesystem of type eCryptfs explicitly disallowed due to known incompatibilities
mount.ecryptfs: Failed to perform eCryptfs mount: [Invalid argument]
kernel: [  197.659287] Reading sb failed; rc = [-22]
```

Answer (score 8):

You mentioned that your home folder is "encrypted by Ubuntu" -- it's actually encrypted using eCryptfs.  Check the output of:

```
grep $HOME /proc/mounts
```

Nesting encrypted directories inside of encrypted directories is not supported with eCryptfs.  Sorry.

*Full disclosure: I'm one of the authors and current maintainers of [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org).*