# Change Location of ecryptfs Private Folder to USB Drive Folder

Tags: kubuntu, encryption, ecryptfs

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.  I've installed ecryptfs and have a ~/Private folder that seems to work fine.  I'd like to change the location of the ~/Private folder to "/dev/sdb1/Private" where sdb1 is a USB drive.

Comment: Change [the mountpoint only](https://askubuntu.com/a/708613/129271) or [move everything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574110/how-to-use-ecryptfs-with-a-non-home-directory)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ecryptfs with a non-home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574110/how-to-use-ecryptfs-with-a-non-home-directory)

Comment: I want to delete the existing ~/Private folder and associated folders and the contents without breaking anything.  Then, I want to create a new rermovable USB hard drive dev/sdb1/Private folder with it's associated folders.