# Encrypting a non-empty folder with ecryptfs

Tags: mount, encryption, ecryptfs

I have some folders with a lot of large files inside them and I would like to encrypt them using ecryptfs.

I am wondering if it is possible to mount a folder that already has files (and subfolders with files) in it, or if I have to make a new empty directory, mount that, and then copy the files over, which is what has worked so far, but I would like to avoid due to the amount of data I would have to copy.

Edit:
some additional information, I am on Ubuntu 20.04.5, and I would also like to encrypt a similar folder on a network drive, not sure if this would change a possible solution at all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ecryptfs with a non-home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574110/how-to-use-ecryptfs-with-a-non-home-directory)

Comment: @guiverc apologies, I am on ubuntu 20.04.5

Comment: I am not sure the other question is exactly what I am looking for, as if I understand it correctly I would still be creating a new directory, whereas I am looking for something more like `mount -t ecryptfs /path/to/mydir /path/to/mydir` (as I would do for an empty folder), but where /path/to/mydir is already populated with files.

Answer (score 1):

eCryptfs (and basically any on-disk encryption like LUKS, etc) only works by encrypting files and writing the encrypted data to disk. There's no shortcut to avoid writing all the data to disk.

If you were just looking for an instant "encrypted view" of your files (maybe to store remotely only), then EncFS can do that with it's `--reverse` option:

If you wanted an automated tool to migrate an existing user's home to an ecryptfs encrypted home setup, there is the `ecryptfs-migrate-home`
tool (in the `ecryptfs-utils` package), but it just automatically creates an encrypted directory, copies the old home into it, then sets it up to be the new home. It has some warnings:

> WARNING:  Make  a  complete  backup  copy  of  the non-encrypted data to another system or external media. This script is dangerous and in case of an error,  could  result  in  data lost, or USER locked out of the system!
>
> This program requires free disk space 2.5x the current size of the home  directory  to  be
> migrated.   Once  successful, you can recover most of this space by deleting the cleartext
> directory.

It sounds like you're already doing ok with manually copying to an encrypted directory, maybe a little automation to copy, verify, then delete a few files at a time would speed things up, but that's a different topic.

---

If you were just looking for an instant "encrypted view" of your files (maybe to store remotely only), then EncFS can do that with it's `--reverse` option, however your original files would remain unencrypted on your disk:

> Normally EncFS provides a plaintext view of data on demand: it stores enciphered data
> and displays plaintext data.  With --reverse it takes as source plaintext data and
> produces enciphered data on-demand.  This can be useful for creating remote encrypted
> backups, where you do not wish to keep the local files unencrypted.
>
> For example, the following would create an encrypted view in /tmp/crypt-view.
>
> ```
> encfs --reverse /home/me /tmp/crypt-view
> ```
>
> You could then copy the /tmp/crypt-view directory in order to have a copy of the
> encrypted data.  You must also keep a copy of the file /home/me/.encfs6.xml which
> contains the filesystem information.  Together, the two can be used to reproduce the
> unencrypted data:
>
> ```
> ENCFS6_CONFIG=/home/me/.encfs6.xml encfs /tmp/crypt-view /tmp/plain-view
> ```
>
> Now /tmp/plain-view contains the same data as /home/me
>
> Note that --reverse mode only works with limited configuration options, so many
> settings may be disabled when used.  Incompatible options as for now : Filename
> Initialization Vector Chaining and External IV Chaining.